# Does salesforce has any function called GetURL

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

In Peoplesoft We have an option called URLIdentifier --> This used to Specify a URL Identifier for a URL that already exists and was created using the URL Maintenance page.

For Example:

URL NAME: SAMPLEURL
Value for Stage ==> 'http://www.peoplesoft.stage.com'
Value for Stage ==> 'http://www.peoplesoft.com'

In Peoplesoft we have an option to add the value from front page(PIA).
If I want to Get this URL in my Code, I can get the URL as **&PS_URL = GetURL(URL.SAMPLEURL);**  , URL name  will be same but the value of the URL will be different for stage and production.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15645_01/pt850pbr0/eng/psbooks/tpcl/chapter.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm%23g037ee99c9453fb39_ef90c_10c791ddc07__3d20

Do we have anything like this in salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are (at least) two pieces of functionality that match this description or which are used for this purpose.

- **Named Credentials** are intended for use with code that makes callouts. They store the URL and handle all authentication for you, so you do not have to be concerned with secure secret storage. Your code is then abstracted from the actual URL.
- **Custom Settings** and **Custom Metadata Types** are used to store general configuration for your application, which could include URLs. Hierarchy Custom Settings can be configured at the level of a user, profile, or the whole org, but aren't visible in test context and cannot be deployed between orgs. Custom Metadata Types are deployable and visible in test context but aren't configurable based on user context.

## Documentation

- [Named Credentials as Callout Endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm)
- [Custom Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm)
- [Custom Metadata Types](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/custom_metadata_types/units/custom_metadata_types_create) (Trailhead)